# find all files contains string in linux

Tags: linux, grep

How can I find all files contains specific string from root level?

I've looged with root & tried something like:

```
[root@ip-172-18-7-96 /]# grep -r 'log4j' /
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Invalid argument
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush: Permission denied
```

I get just several permission denied (although I'm root).

Comment: You're grepping into things that really aren't files, /proc is full of pseudo files. Try `grep -R log4j / 2>/dev/null` to get rid of the noise.

Answer (score 0):

As root, you can still `chmod a-r file`:

```
$ ls -la /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
--w------- 1 root root 0 Sep  4 15:59 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
```